# Entity Framework Code First Auto-create Table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to understand what in the world Entity Framework is doing under the hood that causes the observed behavior I am about to describe.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application project.

I have an existing MSSQL database on localhost called `wpdb`.

Web.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=wpdb;User=xxx;Password=xxx"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I first run the web app, it creates `dbo.UserProfile`, `dbo.webpages_Membership` and a few others tables auto-magically.

I create a new model `Comments.cs`

```
public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class CommentDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I add a new controller `CommentsController` as **MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework** (and select my "Comment" and "CommentDBContext" classes).

Then I add a new connection string (apparently Entity Framework's default connection string isn't "DefaultConnection" but something that ends up being invalid, I'm not sure why).

```
<add name="CommentDbContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=wpdb;User=xxx;Password=xxx"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now when I browse to `localhost/Comments` Entity Framework auto-magically creates a new table in my database called `dbo.Comments`.

**Everything I've described so far is exactly as expected, here's where it's gets weird**

I accidentally deleted `dbo.Comments`. However, this time when I browse to `localhost/Comments` Entity Framework won't recreate the table. Instead it throws an "Invalid object 'dbo.Comments'" error at me.

Why does it do this? Why doesn't it just recreate the database? I even tried deleting all of my Model / Controller / View code, cleaning / rebuilding the solution, and then recreated it all again, and EF still refuses to recreate the table!

What's even more confusing, if I comment out the `CommentDbContext` line in my `Web.config` file (so that the EF code is trying to connect to the wrong database) then run the application and browse to `/Comments`, then kill the app, uncomment the connection string, this time it creates a brand new `dbo.Comments` table without any problems!

Why does changing then connection string to something invalid then changing it back allow EF to generate table from my models again? There seems to be some state being preserved somewhere it shouldn't be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I accidentally deleted dbo.Comments.  it throws an "Invalid object 'dbo.Comments'" error at me. Why does it do this?

Because you aren't suppose to edit/delete the table the way you've configured it.  It is not *syncronizing* database changes to models and models to the database auto-magically.

> Why doesn't it just recreate the database?

Because you haven't told it that automatically, nor have you asked it to.

> Why does changing then connection string to something invalid then changing it back allow EF to generate table from my models again?

Because it creates a table (forgot the name) that knows about the last time it synchronized and what tables it has and hasn't created.  When you change the connection string to a different database that does not have the table, it recreates everything.

You should probably take a look at the following articles on MSDN and choose how you want Entity Framework to work for your scenario:

[Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621)

Comment: `Because it creates a table (forgot the name) that knows` I'd like to know more about this. Can you link me to some documentation?

Comment: I think the one thing this misses is: When he changed it back to the original connection string, why did it decide to then create the missing table?  Why did it not detect the missing change before messing with the connection string at all? I suspect it only checks the entity model on application start, and since it is a MVC app it didn't restart until the webconfig was changed.  I suspect he could have just cycled the app and/or IIS and it would have recreated the table automatically, without messing with the connection string.

Comment: It would pretty expensive anyhow, if every instance of DbContext had to do a full schema compare to determine that the model had changed. Not a criticism of your excellent answer, just some insight for OP on why they don't do this automatically while the app is running.

Comment: @AaronLS You could be correct. The OP has provided no information on how EF is currently configured and I simply don't know the default because I prefer to be explicit in my code so I know exactly what it should be doing.  That and when updating versions, being explicit should provide less code that breaks.

Comment: Agreed, the default behavior is usually only viable for early development, very quickly when moved to staging/production, then migrations are a necessity.

Comment: @AaronLS Aha, that's exactly what happened! I didn't kill the server running in the system tray, and altering Web.config must have forced it to restart. Erik, if you add this to your answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Actually I did mention that *When you change the connection string to a different database that does not have the table, it recreates everything*.  Changing the connection string, change the `web.config` and IIS restarts the application pool when the `web.config` changes.  The table could make a difference depending on the configuration, I simply don't know how you configured it.

Comment: That's not what happened in my situation though. It didn't recreate anything because I changed it to something *invalid*. It was when I changed it *back* that the table was recreated and **only** because the ASP.NET development server had coincidentally restarted. The most important part of the answer is that *changing Web.config causes ASP.NET Development Server to restart*.

Comment: It's actually not coincidentally.  I guess my sentence wasn't clear.  Depending on the configuration, if the table doesn't exist EF will create/recreate the tables.  It's also possible that restarting the server (without changing the web.config) will cause an application start cause EF to create/recreate the tables.  You can also use a NUGET command line.  Or you have called `Database.Initalize()`.  I simply don't know what your code does.

Comment: My code is the default "Internet Application" template in MVC 4. The only thing I did was add a Model / Controller.

Comment: I've honestly never built an application in MVC 4.  Only MVC 3 and 5.  I think MVC 4 uses EF 5? And I've only used EF 4.x and EF 6.1.